# Xamarin.forms Image in emulator but not on device. (android)

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I'm making a simple app in xamarin.forms. It will do a few things but the problem I'm facing now is that I have an image that I want to display on launch.

It does on the Android emulator but not on an actual android device. (My phone)

The image I am trying to present is local and it is in both the "Mobile/Resources/Drawable/image.png" and "Mobile.Android/Resources/Drawable/image.png"

They are also the correct resource setting in the properties too: "Embedded Resource" and "AndroidResource".

Why is it not working? The app launches but images are not present.

EDIT:

My xaml looks like this:

```
<StackLayout
    Orientation="Vertical"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image Source="MainPage.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use the image resources, [Local Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images)  and [Embedded Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#embedded-images). You can choose one in your project.

1) you can use [`Local Images`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images):

```
<Image Source="image.png" 
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

2) you can use [`Embedded Images`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#embedded-images), you don't need put your `image.png` to "Mobile/Resources/Drawable/image.png" path, like android platform. You can copy it to "Moblie/image.png", and then like use it like this:

```
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource Moblie.image.png}
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```